# How to calculate infinite integral in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am trying to prove  the following relation
$$\begin{align*}
   \frac{2j+1}{z} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(1+t)^{2j+2}}[\sum_{n=0}^{2j} [\frac{(2j)!}{(2j- n)! n!}]^{\frac{1}{2}}f_n(\frac{t}{z^*})^n]^* \\ =
\sum_{n=0}^{2j} [\frac{((2j-n)!n!)}{(2j!)}]^{\frac{1}{2}}f^*_n z^{-n-1}  
  \end{align*}$$
That means I have to prove that

$$\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(t^*)^n}{(1+t)^{2j+2}}dt =   \sum_{n=0}^{2j} [\frac{(2j- n)! n!}{(2j)!}] \frac {1}{2j+1}
 \end{align*}$$
where $j= 1/2,1,3/2, 2,\dots $we can choose j equals any value from these values
I go through the proof but I could not find the last relation between the infinite integral and this sum

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What is meant by $f_n$?

Comment: When we expand the sum fn are the coefficients of this series.